# SHGetFileInfo returns default icon from background thread, but correct icon from UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, pinvoke

I have image control which loads icon in different thread

It generally works but for some file extensions (xml, html...) it always returns default icon if retrieved in background thread, but correct icon when retrieved on UI thread.

Why is this happening?

```
        void cIconImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {       
            var source = GetImage(mypath); 
            this.Source = source;       
        }

        private ImageSource GetImage(string mypath)
        {
            ImageSource imgSource = null;   
            icon = ShellIcon.GetSmallIcon(mypath);
            imgSource = icon.ToImageSource();
            imgSource.Freeze();
            return imgSource;   
        }

        private static Icon GetIcon(string fileName, SHGFI flags, bool isFolder = false)
        {
            SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();

    //////For some extensions (xml, html,...) returns default icon
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
Win32.SHGetFileInfo(fileName, isFolder ? FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY : FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo), (uint)(SHGFI.Icon | flags))
                );
    task.Wait(); //temporary 

    //////Everything OK but not in background thread
IntPtr hImgSmall = Win32.SHGetFileInfo(fileName, isFolder ? FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY : FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo), (uint)(SHGFI.Icon | flags));       
    //////

            Icon icon = (Icon)System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon).Clone();
            Win32.DestroyIcon(shinfo.hIcon);
            return icon;
        }
```

GetIcon is part of this class https://gist.github.com/madd0/1433330
but I have tried many different variations of this class with the same result.

Comment: System.Drawing is part of winforms and thus usually dependant on the UI thread.  Try calling SHGetfileInfo on the background thread, but call System.DRawing.Icon.FromHandle on the UI thread...

Comment: @PeterRitchie I tried and it did not work. At least we narrowed the problem to that specific line with SHGetFileInfo.

Comment: How are you declaring SHGetFileInfo?

Comment: @PeterRitchie This is the source https://gist.github.com/madd0/1433330

Comment: Did you initialise COM on the other thread? Do you know that SHGetFileInfo is not threadsafe?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not sure. If SHGetFileInfo is not thread safe then I have to run it in UI thread anyway, right?

Comment: No. Just serialize the calls. But you do need to initialize com. An STAthread I think. I'm no expert on .net.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you mean like this http://pastebin.com/MT5XpKDS

Comment: OK, `STAThread` is just what you use to make the main thread STA. On any other thread you call `Thread.SetApartmentState` before starting the thread. That's it. That will arrange the call to `CoInitializeEx` for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Isn't UI thread main? If I make thread with SHGetFileInfo STA would it be the same as running on UI thread without? I also understand that if I don't set any other thread to STA it is MTA by default. Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: I cannot make any sense of that. You just need to do exactly what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan, your comment led me to solution (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the thread be a single threaded apartment. You do that by calling `SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA)` before the thread starts. Note that you should not call `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx` since that will be done automatically for you. More details on that can be found at this excellent question: [Do i need to call CoInitialize before interacting with COM in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901869/do-i-need-to-call-coinitialize-before-interacting-with-com-in-net)

The other point to make is that `SHGetFileInfo` is not threadsafe. If you have multiple threads that call `SHGetFileInfo` then you will need to serialize those calls to `SHGetFileInfo`.

Comment: So everything is fine except I need to remove CoInitialize and CoUninitialize? It does work without it. Does it mean that even if I create 100s of objects in UI thread calling this code it is fine?

Comment: You have to make sure that all the calls to SHGetFileInfo are serialized. For instance with a lock.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and shows all icons

```
void cIconImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        CoInitialize((IntPtr)0);
        var source = GetImage(mypath);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
                this.Source = source;
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
        CoUninitialize();
    });
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Everything else is the same (except GetIcon does not use Task.Factory)