# How to properly set up a multithreaded Asp.Net MVC + COM server on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, iis, com

## Update 2

The queueing problem was probably solved already, as we've been able to run multiple requests concurrently and the lib nicely reported progress for each operation. Other issues we're still facing about concurrency were likely the reason for this apparent behaviour, but that's a design matter. To solve this however, it'd be helpful to have some knowledge of the inner workings of classes, modules and variables as used in VB6. A question arise: would encapsulating everything (connections, components etc.) in classes ensure that every created object *does not share* any data with other instances?

## Update 1

We've refactored the application a bit more to cope with resource disposing, especially when dealing with OCXs. Apparently that solved the out of memory issue. What still bothers me is that I don't understand what is happening beneath the surface. In this regard, is there a way to see what objects are currently in memory and how many references they have? I know the reference counting model is different from garbage collector-based systems. Still I would suppose the RCW wrapping our com objects would keep things clean for us. In the model given, is that a safe assumption or there's something we're missing?

---

So, I've probably read the most variegated kind of articles and docs about the topic of COM multithreading, but I still cannot get how that's supposed to work exactly, especially when interacting with .Net technologies such as ASP.Net MVC. That could be considered a simple fancy of mine, except for the fact that we've got this quite critical project and we're experiencing severe issues in trying to tie everything up. We're getting out of memory errors (in VB6) and apparently we got wrong how objects are created and data shared between these in COM. Continue reading to know how the story goes...

## How things came to be

Not much to say here. We have a legacy VB6 Desktop application made up of a number of ActiveX DLLs. These are configured to use `Apartment` as the threading model, and all classes are set as `MultiUse`. All worked well and nice until the time came when we was requested to transpose the app on *the mighty web* :O

## The problem we faced and how we (thought we) solved it

Since we haven't got the resources to design and develop a solution from scratch, we used a third party java(script)-based framework to quickly build a web app. However, much of the real work is done by the legacy library, so we needed a way to interface these two components. The easiest way we could think of was to build a very basic (w/o auth and w/o UI) Asp.Net MVC website to use as the middle layer. This would receive requests from the web app and translate them for the COM lib to crunch data.

To this end, and since the libs were never meant to be used as a server, we tried to refactor the whole thing a bit so that most classes can now be used in a standalone manner: this included separating logic from the UI and eliminating all module and public vars where possible; unfortunately, some of the former are still present, in particular some ComponentOne OCXs to handle reports and prints. All in all, this seemed to work just fine, until we had to deal with the *COM threading model* :O

## Making sense of nonsense

Long story short, after a lot of digging and headaches we devised the current solution, which is outlined below:

- we install the legacy app as usual, so that it register its dlls in the registry;
- in our MVC solution, we use `System.Threading.Task`s, one per every request, to start the requested operation in an asynchronous manner. We assign the operation an id and return this id to the client. To start the task we call this method:

  ```
  protected Task<TReturn> StartSTATask<TReturn>(Func<TReturn> function)
  {
      var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                      function,
                      System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                      TaskCreationOptions.None,
                      STATaskScheduler  // property to store the scheduler instance
                      );

      return task;
  }
  ```
- the task is run using the [`STATaskScheduler`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/07/parallelextensionsextras-tour-5-stataskscheduler/). We modified it so that it spawns a new thread if the number of threads in the pool is set to 0.

  ```
  /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the StaTaskScheduler class with the specified concurrency level.</summary>
  /// <param name="numberOfThreads">The number of threads that should be created and used by this scheduler.</param>
  public StaTaskScheduler(int numberOfThreads)
  {
      // Validate arguments
      //if (numberOfThreads < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("concurrencyLevel");

      // Initialize the tasks collection
      _tasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();

      if (numberOfThreads > 0)
      {
          // Create the threads to be used by this scheduler
          _threads = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfThreads).Select(i =>
                     {
                         var thread = new Thread(() =>
                         {
                             // Continually get the next task and try to execute it.
                             // This will continue until the scheduler is disposed and no more tasks remain.
                             foreach (var t in _tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                             {
                                 TryExecuteTask(t);
                             }
                         });
                         thread.Name = "sta_thread_" + i;
                         thread.IsBackground = true;
                         thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

                         return thread;
                     }).ToList();

          // Start all of the threads
          _threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
      }
  }

  /// <summary>Queues a Task to be executed by this scheduler.</summary>
  /// <param name="task">The task to be executed.</param>
  protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
  {
      if (_threads != null)
          // Push it into the blocking collection of tasks
          _tasks.Add(task);
      else
      {
          var thread = new Thread(() => TryExecuteTask(task));
              thread.Name = "sta_thread_task_" + task.Id;
              thread.IsBackground = true;
              thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
              thread.Start();
      }
  }
  ```

  And in our base controller's `OnActionExecuting` method we initiliaze it so

  ```
  STATaskScheduler = HttpContext.Application["STATaskScheduler"] as TaskScheduler;
  if (null == STATaskScheduler)
  {
      STATaskScheduler = new StaTaskScheduler(0);
      HttpContext.Application["STATaskScheduler"] = STATaskScheduler;
  }
  ```
- we use a thin wrapper to instantiate and call our COM libs through reflection:

  ```
  // Libraries is a Dictionary containing the names of the registered dlls
  protected object InitCom(Libraries lib)  
  {
      return InitCom(lib, true);
  }

  protected virtual object InitCom(Libraries lib, bool setOperation)
  {
      var comObj = GetComInstance(lib);

      var success = SetUpConnection(comObj);
      if (!success)
          throw new LeafOperationException(lib, "Errore durante la connessione: {1}".Printf(connectionString));

      if(setOperation)
          return InitOperation(comObj);

      return comObj;
  }

  protected object GetComInstance(Libraries lib)
  {
      var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(MALib[lib]);
      var comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);

      return comObj;
  }

  protected virtual bool DisposeCom(object comObj)
  {
      var success = CloseConnection(comObj);
      if(!success)
          throw new LeafOperationException("Errore durante la chiusura della connessione: {1}".Printf(connectionString));

      //Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comObj);
      //comObj = null;

      return success;
  }

  protected bool SetUpConnection(object comObj)
  {
      var serverName = connectionString.ServerName();
      var catalogName = connectionString.CatalogName();

      return Convert.ToBoolean(comObj.InvokeMethod("Set_ConnectionWeb", serverName, catalogName));
  }

  protected bool CloseConnection(object comObj)
  {            
      return Convert.ToBoolean(comObj.InvokeMethod("Close_ConnectionWeb"));            
  }

  protected object InitOperation(object comObj)
  {
      comObj.GetType().InvokeMember("OperationID", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, comObj, new object[] { OperationId });
      comObj.GetType().InvokeMember("OperationHash", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, comObj, new object[] { OperationHash });

      return comObj;
  }
  ```

  The rationale behind this is that we create a new instance of the class with each request, eventually releasing it when done. Read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous/) to know why we commented out the `ReleaseComObject` part. Basically, we were trading out of memory for a lot of `COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used` exceptions.

  The object is then used like this within methods of various classes:

  ```
  public bool ChiusuraMese()
  {
      try
      {
          PulisciMessaggi();

          var comObj = InitCom(Libraries.Chiusura);
          var byRefArgs = new int[] { 2 };
          var oReturn = comObj.InvokeMethodByRef("ChiusuraMese", byRefArgs, IdDitta, PeriodoGiornaliera, IdDipendenti.PadLeft(), IdGruppoInstallazione, CodGruppoGestione);

          DisposeCom(comObj);

          return Convert.ToInt32(oReturn) == 0;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          using (ErrorLog Log = new ErrorLog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, ex)) { }
          aErrorMessage = ex.Message;
          return false;
      }
  }
  ```

  where `InvokeMethodByRef` is an extension method defined this way:

  ```
  public static object InvokeMethodByRef(this object comObj, string methodName, int[] byRefArgs, params object[] args)
  {
      var modifiers = new ParameterModifier(args.Length);
      byRefArgs.ToList().ForEach(index => { modifiers[index] = true; });

      return comObj.GetType().InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObj, args, new ParameterModifier[] { modifiers }, null, null);
  }
  ```

## Left out of the apartment

For what I understood, this whole apartment stuff is really hard to get right, with its cross-thread marshalling, message loop, yadda yadda whatnot. Add to that we're using and old, unsupported technology used to develop an application that was not architected for the purpose we're forcing it into. All that said, and taken for grant that the .Net side of things is working correctly, a couple of thoughts still wander in our minds. In particular:

- is this the correct way to get advantage of multithreading with COM? Sometimes, multiple requests for the same object get stuck as if queued. This makes us wonder whether COM is actually sharing some instances between threads;
- are we really creating and disposing of objects with each request, or under the hood COM handles things differently? Apparently, we're getting public vars overwritten, so there's probably some resource contention and reentering somewhere we wouldn't expect;
- is the setup correct? Are there alternatives which are easier to maintain and debug? Please keep in mind we don't have neither the time nor the resources to rewrite anything in great extent. We could probably try something like creating an exe ActiveX, but I wouldn't count on that.
- what's the "least worse" way to use OCXs in a project of this kind (not using them is not an option at the moment)? Should we dispose of them in some particular way? We already checked we set them to nothing when finished, but maybe some other thread is still using them;
- should we be aware of any particular COM limit related to our out of memory issue? We encountered the problem before when the form had more than 256 unique controls displayed. Maybe the same is happening here somehow? The error seems to be especially related to classes using UI components.

## Things I've already read (and probably did not understand)

Before you point to resources online I should read, I add here some topics I've encountered, in random order:

#### About SingleUse/MultiUse

- `http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_activex_dll.html`
- `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242108(v=vs.60).aspx`

Not really much choice here, if we want to stick with ActiveX DLLs with forms.

#### About (apartment) threading

- `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716297(v=vs.60).aspx`
- `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716228(v=vs.60).aspx`. By the way, this one probably hints that calls to objects are being serialized for access by other threads.
- `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396`

#### About debugging

- `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241684(v=vs.60).aspx`
- `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716193%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396`

Could a stack dump be of any help when we face the error? I don't even know how to use WinDbg, so I'd like at least to know if that would be a total waste of time :D

We're kinda stuck here, as we've got no clue as to where or what to look for, so any kind of help would be really appreciated.

## Comments

So I've been pointed out I should read more about COM's threading model. I kind of expected that. Anyhow, to elaborate further, let me write some comments.

First, I don't have any control over `CoInitialize` or whatever, I'm just instantiating some VB6 dlls. I guess COM is doing such and such under the hood. Fact is, I could not find anywhere what that is (**edit - apparently, .Net is already taking care of that for me, see the answer to this question: [Do i need to call CoInitialize before interacting with COM in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901869/do-i-need-to-call-coinitialize-before-interacting-with-com-in-net)**).

To recap:

- I'm using STA threads from the client app
- I'm using `Activator.CreateInstance` supposing it is actually creating a new object every time it is called. The call is done within a new STA thread.

Let's set aside for a moment questions about thread-safety in the actual DLLs. What I'm mainly interested in understanding here is if *the described solution* is a correct way (possibly not the best way, I'm aware of that) to exploit multithreading with COM libraries.

To cite some sources, to the best of my current knowledge I should be in the situation depicted in Figure 8.5 here: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716228(v=vs.60).aspx`
I can't find any reason why this should not work, since as I said I'm supposing each object resides in its own apartment and has its own variables, plus a copy of global vars (see here: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261361(v=vs.60).aspx`).

Comment: "Read here to know why we commented out the ReleaseComObject part" that link is nothing but a cop out. The same raining could be applied to IDisposable (don't be lazy about having clearly defined ownership semantics for your expensive resources, then this works just fine). And you should read about COM threading models some more in-depth - at least https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx

Comment: Added some comments to the question.